# Using MERGE in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I just found out about this nifty little feature. I have a couple questions. consider the statement below.

This is how interpret how it works. The USING statement is what gets compared to see if there is a match correct? I want to use how it is now, but I want to use 2 other columns from the source table in the MATCH portion. I can't do that. So is there a way that I can use the 2 columns (decesed (I know its spelled wrong :) ) and hicno_enc)?
Another thing I would like to do and don't know if it possible, but if the row exists in target but not source, then mark it inactive.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SEX1, BIRTH_DATE
FROM 
    aco.tmpimport i
    INNER JOIN aco.patients p 
    ON p.hicnoenc = i.hicno_enc
    MERGE aco.patients AS target
    USING (
            SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SEX1, BIRTH_DATE 
            FROM aco.tmpimport
          ) AS source
    ON target.hicnoenc = source.hicno_enc
    WHEN MATCHED AND target.isdeceased <> CONVERT(BIT,source.decesed) THEN 
        UPDATE 
            SET 
                target.isdeceased = source.decesed, 
                updatedat = getdate(), 
                updatedby = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (firstname, lastname, gender, dob, isdeceased, hicnoenc)
        VALUES (source.FIRST_NAME, 
                source.LAST_NAME, 
                source.sex1, 
                source.BIRTH_DATE, 
                source.decesed, 
                source.hicno_enc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there a way that I can use the 2 columns (decesed (I know its
>   spelled wrong :) ) and hicno_enc)?

Add the columns you need in the select statement in the using clause.

```
USING (
        SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SEX1, BIRTH_DATE, decesed, hicno_enc 
        FROM aco.tmpimport
      ) AS source
```

> if the row exists in target but not source, then mark it inactive.

Add a `when not matched by source` clause and do the update.

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET active = 0
```

Comment: That's one of the things I had mentioned. I am assuming that if I add those 2 columns to the select, it will try and match all those columns to the target correct? Those 2 may be different, so I don't want to match on them, but I do want to be able to use them.

Comment: No. They will not automatically be used in matching just because you have them in the using clause.

Comment: oh, so it only matches on this target.hicnoenc = source.hicno_enc then? excellent.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It only matches on what you have in the `on` clause. And the extra predicates you have after `when matched` is of course also used.